# Using the Google Natural Questions (NQ) Dataset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataset, google-cloud-storage, chatbot, archive

I want to use the Natural Questions (NQ) by Google as the dataset for the chatbot I'm building. I have downloaded the data from Google Cloud with `gsutil -m cp -R gs://natural_questions/v1.0 <path to your data directory>`, but can't figure out how to use this data(I mean unarchive/load to DB/load to a .csv file). The data are present in the form of `.gstmp` archive file format.

The files are named as `nq-train-00.jsonl.gz_.gstmp, nq-train-01.jsonl.gz_.gstmp ...` and so on.

I can't seem to unarchive this file, can anybody help me out with this? Thank you!

This is the link to the dataset: https://ai.google.com/research/NaturalQuestions

Comment: Could you please share the output when you run the following command " gsutil -m cp -R gs://natural_questions/v1.0 <path to your data directory> " ? You are getting .gstmp files because the download is still in progress and these are temporary files.

Comment: Ohh yes... I think that might be the issue. The download crashed once actually. Let me try redownloading the files.

Comment: I've some troubles with the viewing the long answer. Can I see your preprocessing code? It's because when I slice the document text I get an incoherent text, it begins and ends in the middle of some sentences. Here is my email so you can send me the code or a link to a github repo: marius10johan@gmail.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .gstmp files are temporary files which are generated when the download is still in progress or hasn't completed yet per [Google Cloud Platform Github Repository Release 4.14](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/master/CHANGES.md#other-changes-29)